# How to embed diagrams made using d3.js(javascript) into sinatra web application?

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, d3.js

I have drawn some charts and graphs using d3.js file of javascript and I want to embed this charts into a web application(dashboard)using Sinatra?

Answer (score 1):

You can link to the javascript files via script tags defined in a [view](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Views%20/%20Templates). The documentation is a good read.